# Column multiplication and keep the result in separate column

Tags: views

I am trying to create a report where in I want to perform the column  multiplication and keep the result in separate column, say column name as "**total**" and finally need to calculate the sum of the total column. 
So far I have tried with view [calc](https://www.drupal.org/project/calc) module and searched for other option but I am stuck I am not able to achieve this! I have attached a simple report also. Can anyone help on this please?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the [Matrix field](https://www.drupal.org/project/matrix) module? It provides a table with fields in each cell, it's possible to define calculations in some of the field.

I'm the co-maintainer of the module if you have any problems.

Comment: Thanks for your response Colin Shipton: can i use the fields which are from different content type?and create table view and also calculation?reason is i have to get the fields from different content type and do the calculation in view.